# uibuttontypedetaildisclosure custom image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Is it possible to change the image of UIButtonTypeDetailDisclose from the default one to something which is more interesting. However, notice that I'm asking for button, rather for one type of uibutton.

Comment: why don't you use custom button with your images for its different states?

Comment: "notice that I'm asking for button, rather for one type of uibutton.".. can you explain this.?

Comment: You can customize cell accessory view by using a custom button and put it into cell.accessoryView view

Answer (score 1):

you will have to change the accessoryView of the cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath

// code for initializing the cell..

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"interestingImage.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(44.0, 44.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
button.frame = frame;
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(accessoryButtonTapped:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.accessoryView = button;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: this will change the detail button but you lose the disclosure indication of the detail disclosure.  is there anyway to do this and also have the disclosure indicator next to your new custom button?